# sum multi cells has some values app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I using app script have data like that:

[image]

you can see in column D the same hour but the different minutes.

I want to do in column D rows cell has 18:00:10 and another cell 18:10:36...... I need to sum any cell that has 18h... to 18h and in column F multi the values in one cell. and do that in any hour like in image 17:00:10 ......

result like that:

[image]

Comment: is it always .00003 per line?

Comment: can't you split date and time in two columns? It'll make it easier to work with.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating this part that you've mentioned: **`and in column F multi the values in one cell`**? What did you mean with `multi` and on your sample result image on column `F`, how did you get the _0.0094_ result?

Comment: @MattKing no this number its changed

Comment: @IrvinJayG. multi mean cells and sum these cells like L1 + L2 + L3.... ,  0.0094 results? I sum other cells

Comment: I think it would be best if you can share a sheet that you're working on so that we can understand you better and for us to be able to replicate your setup.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const vs = sh.getRange(1, 4, sh.getLastRow(), 3).getDisplayValues();//cols d,e,f
  let sums = { pA: [] };
  vs.forEach(r => {
    let p = r[0].split(":")[0];
    if (!sums.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      sums[p] += r[2];//sum of p
      sums.pA.push(p);//ps
    } else {
      sums[p] += r[2];
    }
  })
  let s = '';//display results
  sums.pA.forEach(p => {
    s += `Hour: ${p} Value:${sums[p]}\n`;
  });
  Logger.log(s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply brother, this code give result like that `10:25:47 PM Info Hour: Time Value:undefinedRate
Hour: Sat Dec 30 1899 21 Value:NaN
Hour: Sat Dec 30 1899 20 Value:NaN` , I don't understand anything

Comment: Please provide me with some data and I'll get it working

Comment: Actually go ahead and try it again.  Getting display values may be all I need because the problem is probably due to the fact that those items are probably either datetimes or durrations.